# Streaming Comet Client didn't receive events for data added using Bulk API?

Tags: bulk-api, streaming-api

I have Streaming comet client with a Pushtopic to an custom object `Business__c` (the pushtopic is enables with **insert,updates and delete** events).
The comet client doesn't generate events based on **insert/upserts/delete** on same object done using **BulkAPI**.

Is it like the Comet Client missing the events due to huge data involving due to bulk api?

Quick suggestion is requested :)

Comment: aalbatross -- no need to prompt the community for rapid response. If someone knows the answer, you'll get a response. Etiquette here is to avoid 'exhortations'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Working with PushTopics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/working_with_pushtopics.htm?search_text=bulk) documentation:

> Updates performed by the Bulk API won’t generate notifications, since such updates could flood a channel.